# PHP timezone issuse with Pacific/Auckland - Getting different value

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

```
    $user_timezone_from =  'UTC';
    $user_timezone_to =  'Pacific/Auckland';
    $date = new DateTime('2015-08-21 14:00', new DateTimeZone($user_timezone_from)); 
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($user_timezone_to)); 
    echo $cur_gmt_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $date = new DateTime('2015-09-29 14:00', new DateTimeZone($user_timezone_from)); 
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($user_timezone_to)); 
    echo $cur_gmt_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I am getting different results  for this.

`2015-08-22 02:00:00`

`2015-09-30 03:00:00` It should be `2015-09-30 02:00:00`

Why I got wrong value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia tells me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country) that on the last Sunday of September there's a DST change in New Zealand. Hence a one hour difference to Summer Time.